# cakephp connection to remote MySql

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to connect my Cakephp project (2.3.8)  to a remote mySQL database.  My connection  the MySQL command line on the same computer

*mysql -u testconection -p -h someserver.somewhere.net*
works perfectly.
But this connection in database.php:

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'someserver.somewhere.net',
    'login' => 'testconnection',
    'password' => 'testpassword',
    'database' => 'db10',
    'prefix' => '',
    //'encoding' => 'utf8',
)
```

fails with this error in Cake:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'someserver.somewhere.net' (13)

according to the the docs  error 13 is a permission denied error.

Thanks

Comment: did you checked login and password? In your example your login is 'test4' but in your code is 'testconection' (with a single 'n')

Comment: Hi Its mysql problem, Contact your support for more help. Check tables are there in that database and ports are opened for access

Comment: Are you using selinux ?

Comment: HI, airila  it was the same login and password.  I was double checked that  (in my post I didnt use a real username and password for security reasons)  I will check in SeLinux  - my deve machine is CentOS which definitly uses SELinux.  the server is Ubuntu Server 12.04  I will double check  on that

Comment: If you Google "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL", without 13, you will get a few links to similar problems related to selinux.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make httpd can make network connection (to MySQL)

```
[roo@web ~]# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```